# Mouseover event over multiple elements flickers

Tags: javascript, html-lists, addeventlistener, mouseover

I’m stuck creating code that’s lean and want to use only JavaScript for now.

http://jsfiddle.net/TheOne_TheMany/30zdkrys

The problem I’m having is the mouseover state, when it goes over the `<li>` it works, but flickers when going over the `<div>` delete area. I know why it does that(After lots of research). So I tried `mouseleave`, but I need to have multiple `ID` on the `<li`> to make it work.

Is there a cleaner way of coding without creating so many ID or multiple event listeners. Especially if I'm going to add more `<li>` or delete them.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I think it is because you have competing mouseover divs and when it animates there is a sweat spot in the middle where they throw the event back and forth.  You may want to provide z-index.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the child `<div>` is in front of the `<li>` when you hover it, so the target is not a `<li>`, but a `<div>`. I'd strongly recommend you to use hover in CSS instead of JavaScript to solve it, but since you want like this, here you go:

Inside the `mouseOver` function, add another if statement to check if the mouse is inside delete button. Then, you add the classes to the `<li>` and the button.

```
const mouseOver = function(item){

    // Btn animation'
    if (item.target === btnSend) {
        item.target.classList.add('btnOver');
    }

    // Li animation
    if (item.target.matches('li')) {
        item.target.classList.add('onLi');
        item.target.lastChild.classList.add('containerDelete');
    }

    if (item.target.matches('.deleteMe')) {
       item.target.parentNode.parentNode.classList.add('onLi');
       item.target.classList.add('containerDelete');
    }

    item.stopPropagation;

}
```

Then, on `mouseLeave` function, add another if statement to check if the mouse is leaving from the `<li>` and delete button.
Inside it, you can also check if the the target is the `<li>` or the button `<div>`, because you have to remove the classes differently.

```
const mouseLeave = function(item){

    // Btn animation   
    if(item.target === btnSend){
        item.target.classList.remove('btnOver');
    } else if (!item.toElement.matches('li') && !item.toElement.matches('.deleteMe')) {
      if (item.target.tagName === 'LI') {
        item.target.classList.remove('onLi');
        item.target.lastChild.classList.remove('containerDelete');
      }
      if (item.target.tagName === 'DIV') {
        item.target.parentNode.parentNode.classList.remove('onLi');
        item.target.parentNode.classList.remove('containerDelete');
        console.log('ok')
      }
    }

}
```

Comment: Amazing. Thanks so much for that, really appreciate it.